# Python OpenCV writing a video without losing frames during device crash

Tags: python, opencv, video, crash

I have the following basic algorithm for writing a video file -

1. Create a cv2.VideoWriter() instance
2. Camera is running in a loop
3. Check if instruction was received to start writing video, if yes - For every new image, perform write() command on the VideoWriter instance to add new image to the video
4. Check if instruction was received to stop writing video, if yes - run release() command on the VideoWriter instance to close the video file and perform some steps to be ready in case instruction for writing video is received again

This works perfectly fine when the instructions for starting and stopping the video writing are received.

However, there is a test condition in which the device which is running this code physically crashes into the wall and essentially would stop working unexpectedly. Obviously, in this case the instruction to stop writing video (from step 4) is not received and the last video on the device is always corrupt.

Is there any way to prevent this? The video on the device (especially just before the crash) is quite important for analysis of the crash.

Comment: don't use mp4. don't use any "container" format at all. use **mpeg transport stream.**, i.e. extension `.mts` or `.m2ts`

Comment: are you sure those aren't container formats too? I'm not used to any other formats apart from container formats...how does the process for creating such videos work?

Comment: well you could call an MPEG Transport Stream a "container" but its structure is more like a "sponge" (packetized elementary streams). I guess I'm just confusing you with this hair splitting. so yes, it's a container format. just tell VideoWriter to make a `.m2ts` or `.MTS` and the ffmpeg backend will know what to do. MPEG TS is the same container format used in BluRays and many handheld cameras.